# Como mostrar un reporte de JasperReport (ireport) en un pdf JSP JAVA

Tags: java, jsp, jasper-reports, ireport

verán tengo un problema, debo desde un boton en un jsp, mandar a llamar a un reporte que he hecho en jasperreport anterioremente y se muestre en una ventana pdf al usuario.

Al dar clic en el boton, debe mandar una señal al servlet y del servlet decidir si muestra el reporte al usuario, entonces devuelve la respuesta al jsp y debe mostrar al usuario el reporte, pero sin embargo, no puedo hacer que lo muestre... por favor ayuda...
mi codigo va así:

FORM Y BOTON DEL JSP:

```
  <!-- este es mi form que se conecta con el servlet Direccion1-->
 <form name="FormReporte" action="Direccion1" method="POST">
        <p style="color:#ffffff">

            Generar Reporte de Pacientes: <br><input type="submit" name="btnreportes" value="GENERAR" class="button1"/>
 <!-- este de acá es mi boton que al darle envía la informacion al servlet-->
        </p>
    </form>
```

EN EL SERVLET: Practicamente solo hago una validacion de si se obtiene un valor String devuelva una respuesta:

```
 //si el boton se pulsa
         } else if (request.getParameter("btnreportes")!=null){
           String respuesta = request.getParameter("btnreportes");//obtiene el value del boton

           request.setAttribute("resreporte",respuesta);//lo coloca en resreporte
         rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("medpacientes.jsp");//manda la respuesta al jsp
         rd.forward(request, response); //termina la instruccion de envio
 }
```

Devuelta en el jsp (donde estaba el boton):

```
  <%
      if(request.getAttribute("resreporte")!=null)//si la respuesta del servlet es diferente de vacía
      {
          //creo mi reporte al usuario, pero es lo que no me deja, siempre me tira error http 500 server

            File reportfile = new File(application.getRealPath("RPacientes.jasper"));
            Map parameter = new HashMap();

            byte[] bytes = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(reportfile.getPath(),parameter, con);

            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            response.setContentLength(bytes.length);
            ServletOutputStream outputstream = response.getOutputStream();
            outputstream.write(bytes,0, bytes.length);
            outputstream.flush();
            outputstream.close();


      }
  %>
```

Por favor pido su ayuda si algo estoy haciendo mal, de antemano Gracias!

Editado:

He movido esto al servlet pero application.getRealPath da error.

```
 File reportfile = new File(application.getRealPath("RPacientes.jasper"));
            Map parameter = new HashMap();

            byte[] bytes = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(reportfile.getPath(), parameter, con);

            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            response.setContentLength(bytes.length);
            ServletOutputStream outputstream = response.getOutputStream();
            outputstream.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            outputstream.flush();
            outputstream.close();
            return;
```

Tengo las siguientes librerías puestas:

```
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.PrintWriter;
 import java.sql.SQLException;
 import java.util.logging.Level;
 import java.util.logging.Logger;
 import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
 import javax.servlet.ServletException;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
 import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
 import java.util.*;
 import java.io.*;
 import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
 import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*;
 import net.sf.jasperreports.view.JasperViewer;
 import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
 import java.sql.Connection; 
 import java.sql.DriverManager;
 import java.sql.SQLException;
 import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
 import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
 import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
 import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
 import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport;
 import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader;
 import net.sf.jasperreports.view.JasperViewer;
 import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
```

APARTE debo aclarar el orden donde tengo ubicado los archivos verán:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

EDITADO 3:

ESTO PASA AL DAR EN EL BOTON DE GENERAR REPORTE, CUANDO TENGO EL CODIGO EN EL SERVLET

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Más sencillo sería el hacerlo directamente en el Servlet. 
Es decir, algo parecido a esto:

```
            // si el boton se pulsa
        } else if (request.getParameter("btnreportes") != null) {
//          String respuesta = request.getParameter("btnreportes");// obtiene el value del boton
//          request.setAttribute("resreporte", respuesta);// lo coloca en resreporte
//          rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("medpacientes.jsp");// manda la respuesta al jsp
//          rd.forward(request, response); // termina la instruccion de envio

            File reportfile = new File(application.getRealPath("RPacientes.jasper"));
            Map parameter = new HashMap();

            byte[] bytes = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(reportfile.getPath(), parameter, con);

            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            response.setContentLength(bytes.length);
            ServletOutputStream outputstream = response.getOutputStream();
            outputstream.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            outputstream.flush();
            outputstream.close();
            return;
        }
    }
```

en este caso no debes invocar a `rd.forward(request, response);`  si no volver directamente a la vista con `return`.

Prueba esto y nos dices.

Comment: Hola gracias por responder, intenté poner el codigo en el servlet como dices, sin embargo, la instruccion application.getRealPath() me da error, dice que no se reconoce la variable application, pero tengo todas las librerías puestas almenos creo yo. Modifiqué la pregunta por si pudieras hechar un ojo, gracias!

Comment: Supongo que tendrás que obtenerlo del servletContext: request.getServletContext().getRealPath("RPacientes.jasper")

Comment: Fijate que lo he hecho como dices y se quitó el error, ahora todo bien ya no muestra el error http 500, pero no me muestra el reporte se queda la pagina en blanco?

Comment: ¿Qué error te da en el log o en la consola?

Comment: Pues la verdad no da ningun error solo que se queda la pantalla en blanco, y  el log del proyecto solamente dice que se corrio satisfactoriamente, pero cuando le doy al boton se queda en blanco la pantalla, y arriba en la barra donde aparece el nombre de la pagina me aparece el nombre del servlet  (Direccion 1), dejé una foto arriba gracias!

Comment: Una vez que ejecutas 'runReportToPdf',  ¿La variable 'bytes' tiene valor?

Answer (score -1):

Despues de

```
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
```

Agrega la siguiente linea

```
 response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + Nombre del reporte + ".pdf");
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).